# How to write a script that does what less does?

Tags: bash, unix, shell

Question: Create a script such that it is a command that has the same effect as the "less" command (implement the script by calling "less").

What I wrote:

```
#! /bin/bash
for index in "$@"
do
  less "$index"
done
```

Apparently this is wrong. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Why not this..

```
#!/bin/bash
less "$@"
```

Although i guess what your teacher meant was to make a script which works like less without using less.

Comment: I know why you are guessing that but your answer was correct...this question is so retarded...

Comment: unless you are asked to add some other functionality, the question your teacher has given doesnt make much sense.

Comment: Well I am guessing he asked such an easy question in our assignment was meant to let us be familiar with the usage of $@....thanks